# Trying to show that this is a $2$-dimensional surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have been working on some problems within multivariate analysis, and I
am trying to go about proving that given the set
$$B = \{(u,v) \in [0,1] \times [0,1] | u < v\}$$
and the set
$$Q = \{(1+uv,u^2-v^2,1-uv) | (u,v) \in B\}$$
that $Q$ is a $2$-dimensional surface. Let us set the function
$\phi(u,v) = (1+uv,u^2-v^2,1-uv).$
I've been trying to solve for the inverse of $\phi$ by setting
$x = 1+uv$, $y = u^2-v^2, z = 1-uv$, and then solving for $u$ and $v$ in
terms of $x,y,$ and $z$, but I seem to keep running into potenetial issues.
I can tell that I do have the constraint that
$x + z = 2,$
But give that
$x = 1+uv \implies \frac{x-1}{u} = v$
$$\implies y = u^2 - \left(\frac{x-1}{u}\right)^2,$$
I am having issues solving for a closed form of $u$ in this problem. Any
suggestions?